# Carmichael numbers with prime factors = 3,5 mod 8

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A Carmichael number $n$ is a number of the form $n=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ where $p_i$ are distinct odd primes and $p_i-1$ divides $n-1$ for each $i=1,\dots,k$. It is known that there exist infinitely many Carmichael numbers, with asymptotic density $> N^{1/3}$.

Do there exist infinitely many Carmichael numbers $n$ with all its prime factors either 3 or 5 mod 8? That is, $p_i\equiv \pm 3$ mod $8$ for each $i$.

One such number is $n=13\times 37\times 61 = 29341$.

Comment: Can there be prime factors of each kind or are they exclusively either $3$ or $5 \pmod{8}$?

Comment: There can be prime factors of both kinds.

Comment: Perhaps of note: if you believe the prime $k$-tuples conjecture, there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers with prime factors all 1 mod 6.  This follows from an observation of Chernick.

Comment: I think your best bet may be to track through the paper "There are Infinitely Many Carmichael Numbers" by Alford, Granville, and Pomerance.  They construct Carmichael numbers with many prime factors, and you could attempt to impose congruence conditions at that point.